# Coming up with a list of duplicates that appear in list of list except under certain conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of list of tasks types and projects associated with them. There are 4 types of tasks in total. I would like to generate a list of Projects with multiple tasks types except when with certain pairs of task types. I have figured out how to get a list of projects with multiple tasks but not how to exclude the exclusion combinations.

Combination pairs to exclude from output
(task type 1, task type 4), (task type 3, task type 4)

If a project has an exclusion pair in addition to others, it should be included in the output.

Input:

```
my_list = [['Task Type 1', 'Project 1'],['Task Type 2', 'Project 1'],['Task Type 4', 'Project 1'],
          ['Task Type 3', 'Project 2'],['Task Type 4', 'Project 2'],
          ['Task Type 1', 'Project 3'],['Task Type 1', 'Project 3'],
          ['Task Type 4', 'Project 4']]
```

Start to Code:

```
from collections import Counter
my_project_list = zip(*my_list)[1]
cnt = Counter(my_project_list)
my_duplicate_list = [k for k, v in cnt.iteritems() if v > 1]
print my_duplicate_list
```

Desired Output:

```
['Project 1', 'Project 3']
```

Comment: OP also stated that a minimum length of 2 is to be applied to rejection condition (In my answer it's a parameter with 2 as default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

First, we'll create a mapping from project to a list of it's types.

Then, we'll create a filter that receives a list of rules and returns only projects who match any of the rules.

So here is the full code with detailing (fixed thanks to @DSM):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [
    ['Task Type 1', 'Project 1'],
    ['Task Type 2', 'Project 1'],
    ['Task Type 4', 'Project 1'],
    ['Task Type 3', 'Project 2'],
    ['Task Type 4', 'Project 2'],
    ['Task Type 1', 'Project 3'],
    ['Task Type 1', 'Project 3'],
    ['Task Type 4', 'Project 4']
]

# create mapping according to our filter value
# in our case, project to it's types
projects_to_types = defaultdict(list)
for x in my_list:
    projects_to_types[x[1]].append(x[0])

# sort all lists of types - this promises
# the equation of two identical lists
# returns the same results (lists have order)
projects_to_types = {k:sorted(v) for k, v in projects_to_types.iteritems()}

# a function to create a filter over a mapping
# like the one we created, the filter is a generator
def rules_filter_generator(original):
    # take a list of rules and filter out keys whose
    # values match any rule
    def filter_restricted(rules, minimum_length=2):
        # a set will give us better, more readable and faster code.
        # convert to tuples since list isn't hashable (mutable).
        rule_set = set(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), rules))
        for k, v in original.iteritems():
            if len(v) >= minimum_length and not tuple(v) in rule_set:
                yield k
    return filter_restricted

# use the filter specifically on the mapping we've created
generator = rules_filter_generator(projects_to_types)

# test (consume the generator to a list)
print list(generator([
    ['Task Type 3', 'Task Type 4'],
    ['Task Type 3', 'Task Type 3', 'Task Type 4']
]))

# prints: set(['Project 3', 'Project 1'])
```

Comment: This is really interesting and all new to me. I set the filter (last line) to a value then print the value, I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. How am I misusing this?

Comment: @user2242044 I added the full code. SyntaxError usually means you've mis-typed something.

Comment: Your `type_to_projects` line will effectively ignore all but the last project of a given type.  Was that intended?

Comment: @DSM no, I needed to use `defaultdict(list)` and fix the set, fixing, thanks :)

Comment: @user2242044 use new full code which now works as expected, fixing answer.

Comment: @ReutSharabani this is only returning `set(['Project 3'])`

Comment: @user2242044 project 3 has type 4, isn't that what's expected? or do you want an `all` condition rather than `any`? :) It's easily fixable.

Comment: @ReutSharabani, it should return Project 3, but it should also return Project 1

Comment: @user2242044 so you want to remove all projects that have *all* of the types rather than *any* of the types?

Comment: @ReutSharabani I want projects with multiple tasks, but if a project has two tasks (with no other tasks) that are an acceptable combination it does not need to be included.  Project 1 has task type 1 and 4 which is an acceptable combination, but it also has type 2 and therefore has multiple types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69699/discussion-between-reut-sharabani-and-user2242044).